# Create a file download link using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a download link on my page but it doesn't work and get error. 
Here's my code.

request mapping :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/download", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    // Load file from database
    MsFile file = null;
    MsAnnouncement ano = null;
    try {
        ano = anRepo.findById(id).get();
        file = fileService.getFile(ano.getFileId().getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getFileType()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getAttachedFileName() + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(file.getAttachedFile()));
}
```

html :

```
        <a class=" mx-1 btn btn-secondary" th:href="@{/admin/announcement/{id}/download/(id=${announcement.id})}" 
                            >Download</a>
```

I just need the file downloaded once when i click the button. But when i try with this code the file cannot be downloaded and get error at the return ResponseEntity.ok():

error following :

```
AnnouncementController.downloadFile(AnnouncementController.java:130) ~[classes/:na]
```

At java:130 :

```
   return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getFileType()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getAttachedFileName() + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(file.getAttachedFile()));
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. What error do you get?

Comment: is the href correct on the html side?? Also are you able to download file via curl or postman.

Comment: `<a class=" mx-1 btn btn-secondary" th:href="@{/admin/announcement/{id}/dowload/(id=${announcement.id})}" ` The spelling of download is wrong.

Comment: yes, i found it hhehehe just about the spelling :D